# The ConnectionString property has not been initialized Error with Dapper

Tags: c#, .net, ado.net, dapper

My code to execute an SQL insert command is like this

```cs
foreach (var id in idlist)
{
    _connection.Open();
    var sql = "sql query"
    var parameters = ....

    await _connection.ExecuteAsync(sql, parameters);
    _connection.Close();
}
```

All looks good, But the loop runs successfully only once, when it enters a second time it throws an error

```
The ConnectionString property has not been initialized.
```

Can anyone please point out what I may be doing wrong here?

Note: I have tried moving the connection open and close out of the loop too, But still the same result.

Comment: Is it possible to print value of "connectionstring" property before calling " _connection.Open()" and check how and where its value is getting cleared out?

Comment: Generally, the way you work with a SqlConnection is you create one, you open it, you use it and then you close or dispose it. Either leave yours open or create a new one per query (the are effectively a lightweight facade in front of a pool of connections)

Comment: Allow Dapper to handle Open and Close. Here, you do not need to open the connection before sending it to Dapper. If the input connection is not in an Open state, Dapper will open it - Dapper will do the actions - Dapper will close the connection. There is some hidden code in there which is causing the _connection to be reinitialized with no connection string

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code should look like:

```
_connection.Open();
var sql = "sql query"

foreach (var id in idlist)
{
    var parameters = ....
    await _connection.ExecuteAsync(sql, parameters);
}
_connection.Close();
```

If you're executing only once, omit the open and close (Dapper will do it), unless your connection is enrolled in a transaction

`_connection` is named like as if it's a class level variable. Be sure that you aren't manipulating it elsewhere while the loop is running. I wouldn't say you gain much by holding a reference to a connection, perhaps consider:

```
using var connection = new SqlConnection("your conn string");
connection.Open();
var sql = "sql query"

foreach (var id in idlist)
{
    var parameters = ....
    await _connection.ExecuteAsync(sql, parameters);
}
connection.Close();
```

Error handling will vary according to what you want to do if eg one insert fails mid batch - dump it all, halt and fix, ignore and proceed.

Comment: minor suggestion: `SqlConnection` is `IDisposable`, so: `using var connection = new SqlConnection("your conn string");`